# pairwise independence implies independence for the multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $(X_1, \ldots, X_N) \sim \mathcal{N(\bf{\mu}, \bf{\Sigma})}$ is multivariate normal, then I've seen that pairwise independence implies independence ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)).

How do you prove this fact? I thought maybe I could use characteristic functions but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: If all covariances are zero then $P\{X_1\le x_1,...,X_N\le x_N\}=P\{X_1\le x_1\}\times ... \times P\{X_N\le x_N\}$. You can verify this easily...

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes, but that works only if the covariances are zero.

Comment: @MichaelHardy But pairwise independence implies zero covariances...

Comment: ok, I was hasty ... I was thinking about various characterizations of the multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: BTW notice the difference between $P\{X_1\le x_1\}\times ... \times P\{X_N\le x_N\}$ and $P\{X_1\le x_1\}\times \ldots \times P\{X_N\le x_N\}$ and $P\{X_1\le x_1\}\times \cdots \times P\{X_N\le x_N\}$ and $P\{X_1\le x_1\}\times \text{...} \times P\{X_N\le x_N\}$.  They all four look conspicuosly different.  The last one is what you will see if you write "..." in math mode in LaTeX.  In MathJax (which is what is used here) the first one is what you see.  the second and third result from use of \ldots and \cdots respectively.  Those two are within the bounds of standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @d.k.o. Having some trouble computing $F$.

Comment: Two good characterizations of the multivariate normal distribution are the following: (1) $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is so distributed that every linear combination $a_1 X_1+\cdots+a_n X_n$, where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are constants (i.e. not random) has a univariate normal distributions. (2) $(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = (Z_1,\ldots,Z_k)A$ for some $k\times n$ matrix $A$, where $Z_1,\ldots,Z_k$ are independent normals with expectation $0$ and variance $1$.

Comment: $f(x_1,...,x_N)=(2\pi)^{-N/2}(\prod_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{ii})^{-1/2}\exp(- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu_i)^2/\Sigma_{ii})$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I went for the second one in my proof, do you think it works?

Answer (score 0):

The joint ChF is $\varphi_{{\bf X}} ({\bf u}) = \exp \left( i {\bf u}^T {\bf \mu} - \frac{1}{2} {\bf u}^T {\bf \Sigma} {\bf u} \right)$. Since the pairwise covariances are zero ${\bf \Sigma}$ is diagonal, and ${\bf X} \overset{d}{=} {\bf \Sigma}^{1 / 2} {\bf Z} + {\bf \mu}$ where ${\bf Z} \sim \mathcal{N} ({\bf 0}, I_n)$, but the components of the latter are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that long expressions do not fit into comments. So, I'll leave my last comment here...

\begin{align}
F(x_1,...,x_N)&=(2\pi)^{-N/2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{ii}\right)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{x_N}  \exp\!\left(-\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{(z_i-\mu_i)^2}{2\Sigma_{ii}}\right)dz_1\cdots dz_N\\
&=(2\pi)^{-N/2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{ii}\right)^{-1/2}\prod_{i=1}^N\int_{-\infty}^{x_i}\exp\!\left(-\frac{(z_i-\mu_i)^2}{2\Sigma_{ii}}\right)dz_i=\prod_{i=1}^N F(x_i).
\end{align}

Comment: Why does the joint distribution factorize?

Comment: Because $\exp(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^N \exp(x_i)$ so that the joint distribution is a product of its marginals.